# Not able to get record from getResults() using RESTlet in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have the RESTlet file in the following link. 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ganeshprabhus/a3ebd67712913df3de29/raw/eb2a67c1989181a2b0646083af0913070ad520ee/ns_script.js

i call the RESTlet file using php by the following format.

```
$datastring = array('recordtype' => 'customer','gu_action'=>'get_all','size' => 100,'index'=>0);
```

here before it was working fine. but now sometimes the i am not able to get records.

The actual process is getting all the records of particular record type based on 
last modified date. I have done the code based on this post [Get records by page wise in Netsuite using RESTlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369206/get-records-by-page-wise-in-netsuite-using-restlet)

i) It searches all the records which are having record type as customer order by last modified date descending.

```
var NS_filters = new Array();
var columns = new Array();
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('lastmodifieddate').setSort(1);

var search = nlapiCreateSearch(datain.recordtype, NS_filters, columns)
```

ii) After searching i get result

```
var results = search.runSearch();
var records = results.getResults(INDEX, MAX_SIZE);
```

index & max_size like (0,100) , (100,200), (200,300)

After all records was fetched , i get empty value from records. But now sometimes i get empty value from records for some indexes randomly.

```
Ex : 
index 0 - got result
index 1 - got result 
index 2 - no result //i thought all records fetched , but still available
index 3 - no result
index 4 - got result
```

This is the problem. I am very struggling to find and solve the issue.

Help me to solve the problem or should i follow any other different way to search better than this.

Comment: Could you try to do searching directly to NS account and see if you have the same result. It might be a native error.

Comment: Did you tried to debug and see the result objects you are retrieving. Also you can try running a UI saved search and match with your script search to ensure your script is giving you correct results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And Sorry issue is not in RESTlet. The issue is converting json data to array using json_decode in php